# double free or corruption with OpenMP parallel do

Tags: fortran, openmp, subroutine

I am trying to speed up a sequential fortran95 code with OpenMP like the below. I cannot determine where/how to handle private, shared, reduction, etc. clauses for the variables in the subroutine and function.

```
 PROGRAM main
  integer       :: i, j, n, nw, nocsf
  real(kind=dp) :: energy
  type(nkappa)  :: subshell
  integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: ndx
  n = asf_final%csf_set%nocsf + asf_initial%csf_set%nocsf
  allocate( auger_csp%P(1:n_grasp2k), auger_csp%Q(1:n_grasp2k) )
  allocate( cowf_csp%P(1:10), cowf_csp%Q(1:10) )
  allocate( ndx(1:n) )

  !$omp parallel do
  !$omp& shared(auger_csp,cowf_csp,ndx, n) 
  !$omp& private(nw,nocsf,energy,subshell)
  do  i = 1,number_of_transitions
     do  j = 1,transition(i)%number_of_channels
      energy = transition(i)%energy
      auger%no_f = asf_cont%csf_set%nocsf
      ......
      nw = asf_cont%csf_set%nwshells
      nocsf = asf_cont%csf_set%nocsf
      call anco_calculate_csf_matrix(asf_cont%csf_set,1,nocsf,1,nocsf)
      subshell = nkappa(-1,transition(i)%channel(j)%kappa)
      call cowf_iterate_csp(energy,subshell)
        ......
        auger_csp = cowf_csp
        ......
      allocate( auger%ndx_i(auger%no_i) )
        ......
      deallocate( auger%ndx_f, auger%ndx_i, auger%matrix  )
      call deallocate_csf_basis(asf_cont%csf_set)
     end do
     call auger_transition_properties(transition(i))
  end do
   !$omp end parallel do
  deallocate( ndx, auger_csp%P, auger_csp%Q)
  END PROGRAM
```

It reports that

```
"Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.
 double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007f1490000ac0 ***

Backtrace for this error:

Allocation would exceed memory limit"
```

Could anyone please give me some suggestions? Your expert help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Then, present us a clear description of what are you trying to do, what you got wrong and what you expected to get, along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
When reading your question I get that you have a problem with (understanding?) omp. So please create a MCVE that illustrates the problem you have, a not  "a sequential fortran95 code with OpenMP like the below".

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Many more people will see your question.

Comment: If your private arrays are of tractable size and so on, you may be able to deal with this by setting OMP_STACKSIZE and possibly overall stack to realistic values.

Comment: Your latest edit https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57642750/revisions did not reallly help much. We are still missing a real [mcve] that we could compile and try to run.  It contains undeclared variables and types and elipses.

Comment: If that's really your code, I'd delete one of the `!` in `!!$omp end parallel do` and compile again ....